# How to download multiple files in Minio as an archive

Tags: .net, minio, minio-client

I store files in Minio with a link to a specific entity via tags.
The user can add and delete them.
I need a way to download them all at once as an archive.

I don't understand if it's possible to download them all at once as an archive in Minio.
Or, for example, first create an archive on the Minio side, and then download it.

Due to the nature of the project, I want to avoid creating an archive on my application side (memory or hard drive)

I couldn't find anything on Google about this.

I'm using a .net client, but that shouldn't be important.